# Access Google spreadsheets with OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-sheets-api, gdata-python-client

I'm trying to access Google spreadsheets using gdata-python-2.0.17 library. In every tutorial, *programmaticLogin(uname,pwd)* is used but I feel it is not a good practice. I'm trying to overcome this by using OAuth 2.0 authentication(oauth2client.client). 
I've managed up to granting access to a Google account by getting user consent.

I'm not sure whether the standard *gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()* can be used in this scenario.
According to [this](http://www.eksod.com/2013/01/google-python-api-reviewsample-code/), it is not possible/easy to combine OAuth 2.0 and gdata-python library.
It's highly appreciated if someone know how to handle this with the said APIs or using later versions of Google API which can be used.

Thanks

Comment: There was no docs (here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) on how to do Java OAuth2 but it was possible. Looks like you need to find/write the code to pass the OAuth token.

Comment: I had a similar problem and solved it with this pattern in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925125/accesstokenrefresherror-google-spreadsheet-api-with-oauth-2-0-service-account-o