# AccessTokenRefreshError: Google Spreadsheet API with oAuth 2.0 Service Account of App Engine App

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, gdata-python-client

I'm trying to access a Google Spreadsheet via the GData API using oAuth 2.0 service-account credentials created for a Python 2.7 app hosted on Google App Engine.

1. The app uses the recent gdata-python-client from Google, v. 2.0.18 (gdata and atom).
2. The app uses the recent google-api-python-client-gae, v. 1.2.
3. In the Google Developer Console for this project (in this example referred to as "my-gae-app"), I have created a Service Account and delegated domain-wide authority to the service account [as described here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount)
4. The desired spreadsheet in Google Drive belongs to a Google Apps for Work domain, here referred to as "mygoogleappsdomain.com".
5. I have granted read+write access for the spreadsheet to `my-gae-app@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` and to the email address shown for this service account and which is assigned to `clientEmail` variable in the code below. Not sure which of the two email addresses would be actually needed, so I assigned both. The user with the `impersonateUser` email address also has read+write access to this spreadsheet.

With Google API Python Client's `AppAssertionCredentials` I can access the meta-data of the desired spreadsheet via the Google Drive API. However, if I try to access the spreadsheet's content using gdata, I'm getting errors. The best result I could get so far with the service account is using `SignedJwtAssertionCredentials`, [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026286/using-oauth2-with-service-account-on-gdata-in-python). However, I'm stuck with this `AccessRefreshTokenError: access denied` and I don't understand what's going wrong.

```
import os
import httplib2
from google.appengine.api import memcache
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
import gdata.spreadsheets.client
import gdata.spreadsheet.service

# AppAssertionCredentials is not supported in gdata python client library,
# so we use SignedJwtAssertionCredentials with the credential 
# file of this service account.
# Load the key in PKCS 12 format that you downloaded from the Google API
# Console when you created your Service account.
clientEmail = '10346........-g3dp......................3m1em8@developer.gserviceaccount.com'
p12File = 'app.p12'
path = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'data', 'oAuth2', p12File)
impersonateUser = 'user@mygoogleappsdomain.com'
spreadsheetKey = '1mcJHJ...................................juQMw' # ID copied from URL of desired spreadsheet in Google Drive
with open(path) as f:
    privateKey = f.read()
    f.close()

# Getting credentials with AppAssertionCredentials only worked successfully
# for Google API Client Library for Python, e.g. accessing file's meta-data.
# So we use SignedJwtAssertionCredentials, as suggested in
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026286/using-oauth2-with-service-account-on-gdata-in-python
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    clientEmail,
    privateKey,
    scope=(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file ',
        # added the scope above as suggested somewhere else,
        # but error occurs with and with-out this scope
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
        'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
        'https://docs.google.com/feeds'
    ),
    sub=impersonateUser
)

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
auth2token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2TokenFromCredentials(credentials)
# error will occur, wether using SpreadsheetsService() or SpreadsheetsClient()
#srv = gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()
#srv = auth2token.authorize(srv)

clt = gdata.spreadsheets.client.SpreadsheetsClient()
clt = auth2token.authorize(clt)
# Until here no errors

wks = clt.get_worksheets(spreadsheetKey)
# AccessTokenRefreshError: access_denied
```

This is the error I get in the remote shell:

```
s~my-gae-app> wks = clt.get_worksheets(spreadsheetKey)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "gdata/spreadsheets/client.py", line 108, in get_worksheets
    **kwargs)
  File "gdata/client.py", line 640, in get_feed
    **kwargs)
  File "gdata/client.py", line 267, in request
    uri=uri, auth_token=auth_token, http_request=http_request, **kwargs)
  File "atom/client.py", line 122, in request
    return self.http_client.request(http_request)
  File "gdata/gauth.py", line 1344, in new_request
    refresh_response = self._refresh(request_orig)
  File "gdata/gauth.py", line 1485, in _refresh
    self.credentials._refresh(httplib2.Http().request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 653, in _refresh
    self._do_refresh_request(http_request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 710, in _do_refresh_request
    raise AccessTokenRefreshError(error_msg)
AccessTokenRefreshError: access_denied
```

I'm not sure if this indicates that this service-account is denied access to the spreadsheet, or if there was an error with refreshing the access token. Do you know what's wrong with this code or setup?

Comment: its probably access to the spreadsheet.  Think of a service account as a person. If random user X doesn't have access to that sheet then neither does the service account.  I am not sure if you can or not but try taking the service account email and giving it access like you would Random user X.

Comment: I didn't know which email address to use in the spreadsheet file when adding read+write access, so I used both addresses, the actual email address of the GAE app, e.g. "my-gae-app@appspot.gserviceaccount.com" and that very long cryptically looking email address of the service account, e.g. "10346........-g3dp......................3m1em8@developer.gserviceaccount.com". I'm not sure if I have to use one of them as "sub" parameter when calling `SignedJwtAssertionCredentials()`. Currently it uses a normal user email in our Google Apps domain who also has read+write access to this file.

Comment: that very long cryptically looking email address of the service account gotten from when you create it.  Is the one you should be using as that is the User identification for the service account.  it paired with the key file you download is what makes up service account login

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured out that calling `SignedJwtAssertionCredentials` with-out the `sub` parameter (for the "impersonated" user) will not produce `AccessTokenRefreshError: access_denied`

```
import os
import httplib2
from google.appengine.api import memcache
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
import gdata.spreadsheets.client
import gdata.spreadsheet.service

# AppAssertionCredentials is not supported in gdata python client library,
# so we use SignedJwtAssertionCredentials with the credential 
# file of this service account.
# Load the key in PKCS 12 format that you downloaded from the Google API
# Console when you created your Service account.
clientEmail = '10346........-g3dp......................3m1em8@developer.gserviceaccount.com'
p12File = 'app.p12'
path = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'data', 'oAuth2', p12File)
impersonateUser = 'user@mygoogleappsdomain.com'
spreadsheetKey = '1mcJHJ...................................juQMw' # ID copied from URL of desired spreadsheet in Google Drive
with open(path) as f:
    privateKey = f.read()
    f.close()

# Getting credentials with AppAssertionCredentials only worked successfully
# for Google API Client Library for Python, e.g. accessing file's meta-data.
# So we use SignedJwtAssertionCredentials, as suggested in
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026286/using-oauth2-with-service-account-on-gdata-in-python
# but with-out the sub parameter!
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    clientEmail,
    privateKey,
    scope=(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file ',
        # added the scope above as suggested somewhere else,
        # but error occurs with and with-out this scope
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
        'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
        'https://docs.google.com/feeds'
    ),
#    sub=impersonateUser
)

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
auth2token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2TokenFromCredentials(credentials)
# this pattern would eventually also work using SpreadsheetsService()
# SpreadsheetsService methods are different from SpreadsheetsClient, though
#srv = gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()
#srv = auth2token.authorize(srv)

clt = gdata.spreadsheets.client.SpreadsheetsClient()
clt = auth2token.authorize(clt)

wks = clt.get_worksheets(spreadsheetKey)
# works now!
```